# WHERE do SQL retorna valores indesejados

Tags: mysql, where

```
SELECT x, y, z, f , g , h 
FROM torrents
INNER JOIN w ON w = x
WHERE y =  '2' OR y =  '7'
AND  f =  '1'
AND h < 4294967296
```

Eu setei o `f = '1'` no `where` para que ele me retorne somente os valores com `f = 1` so que ele retorna valores com 0 e também me retorna valores com o Size maior.

Ex:

[image: screenshot parcial]

Comment: As colunas Y e F são INT ou VARCHAR? Posta ai a estrutura da tabela.

Comment: Já consegui resolver , obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o `OR` é apenas no Y, precisa de parenteses, senão qualquer `y = 2` retorna, independente dos valores de `f` e `h`.

Fora isto, tem que ver se o `JOIN` está correto, melhor seria não usar nomes iguais nos campos e nas tabelas.

Possível solução (corrija o `tabela1.w` para o nome do campo certo):

```
SELECT x, y, z, f , g , h 
FROM torrents AS tabela1
INNER JOIN w  AS tabela2
           ON tabela1.w = tabela2.x
WHERE ( y =  '2' OR y =  '7' )
AND  f =  '1'
AND h < 4294967296
```

Se quiser deixar um pouco mais elegante, pode usar `IN` e tirar as aspas:

```
SELECT x, y, z, f , g , h 
FROM torrents
INNER JOIN w ON w = x
WHERE y IN ( 2, 7 )
      AND f = 1
      AND h < 4294967296
```

Comment: Obrigado , estou aprendendo SQL ainda e me colocaram pra mecher nisso na empresa estava batendo cabeça .

Comment: As estruturas acho melhor não porque é do sistema da empresa , não quero que der rolo pra min.

Comment: @ArthurAires era só usar o `DESCRIBE nome_da_tabela`, copia e colar, não existe mostrar dados.

Comment: OK, quando chegar em casa faço , obrigado!